# How to check if int variable is not equal to String in jstl?

Tags: java, jstl

I have a "size" stored in database its value can be `9, M or null`. When I'm extracting the data in `jstl` using `<c:when>` condition and comparing if it's not equal to `null` string I get this error:

```
Cannot convert null of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
```

Code I have used to compare the value:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${product.productBeanSize ne 'null'}">
        <td>${product.productBeanSize}</td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <td></td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: There is no `int` variable here, or if there is the test is pointless, as`int` variables cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if `"null"` is stored as a string in your DB or if it indicates simply a not valorized value.

In the latter case simply check:

```
<c:if test="${not empty product.productBeanSize}">
    <td>${product.productBeanSize}</td>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty product.productBeanSize}">
    <td></td>
</c:if>
```

Otherwise (but why you should save the "null" string, simply leave the column not valorized) you can try with `<c:catch>` to check if the value is numeric.
Example:

```
<c:set var="size" value="${product.productBeanSize}" />
<c:catch var="isNumber">
   <c:set var="size" value="${size * 1}" />
</c:catch>
```

If `isNumber` is == `null` then you have a numeric value, otherwise a string one.